# How can one move text in FTGL in C?

Tags: c, opengl, fonts

I may have missed something but I see here on header files all kinds of functions to move text around in C++ but not on the C API. How is it done?

EDIT: Pixmap fonts for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `glTranslatef()` or `glRasterPos2f()`.

Also, what documentation are you looking at?  [I'm not seeing any positioning functionality](http://ftgl.sourceforge.net/docs/html/).